# How can I install Apache Solr into a specified directory in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: solr, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Apache Solr into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have used the following commands:

```
cd /vm
sudo wget http://apache-mirror.8birdsvideo.com/lucene/solr/8.2.0/solr-8.2.0.tgz
tar xzf solr-8.2.0.tgz solr-8.2.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-8.2.0.tgz -d /vm
```

I am trying to install everything into a folder `/vm`. 
But it throws an error and installs everything under `/opt`. 
Everything works fine and I am able to add core, add a document, etc.

I want to be able to install it into my specified folder and I am not able to find an option for that. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to give the *install directory* is `-i /vm`. `-d` configures the *data directory*.

The [example from the manual that replicates the default settings](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html):

```
sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.6.0.tgz -i /opt -d /var/solr -u solr -s solr -p 8983
```

Comment: thanks for the update, but this can be executed only as a root user

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - your own example above also uses `sudo` to run the command as the root user. You do not need to include the `-u` and `-s` parameters, as they're shown as a standard. In general, to install Solr _as a service_ under Linux that starts automagically after a reboot, you will have to be root at some point.

Comment: I am running as a user with Sudo permissions. Still, I get the error asking to run as the root user.